# why am I not seeing my html or any kind of error?

Tags: javascript, html

I have my code that I am trying to see, its suppose to ask me for login info then when I click submit it should POST to a php script but when I run this script I see nothing, white blank screen and no errors...any ideas? this file is named login.php html body is not showing...

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Authentication</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action='loginLDAP.php' method='post' name='Auth'>

<?php TabTop("Please Login"); ?>
Please log in using your user name and your
portal password:<p>

<table cellspacing=3 cellpadding=3 class=ContentBodyTable>
   <tr>
      <td>Username: </td>
      <td><input type=text name=login size=16 maxlength=15 class=textInput></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Password: </td>
      <td><input type=password name=password size=16 maxlength=15 class=textInput></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan=2><input type=submit value=Authenticate class=SubmitInput style='width:100'></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php TabBot(); ?>

<!-- Set the focus to the login text field onload. -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   document.Auth.login.focus();
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just did, I get nothing error_reporting(-1);...Html body is not showing...

Comment: Make sure that `loginLDAP.php` exists in the same folder. If your file is hosted at a Linux server (very likely), make sure that your file name is spelled correctly: The file names are case-sensitive.

Comment: I did check that nothing wrong there either. I will just redo a new form.

Comment: Remove the PHP code from your page and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting rid of the  < p > at line 12. If that doesn't work, try commenting out the tabtop() call. If this gives you the form, then debug that script. It looks as though that script has a logic error, not a syntax one, so no syntax error.

Comment: thanks! was stuck on this from forever, the tabtop was the problem